# IText 7, get transparency of text (reference to ExtGState)

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I have PDF with two simple texts. One of which contains transparency. The text object contains a reference to ExtGState which has transparency value. 
**How I can get this value?**

There is picture from debug tool (pdf apache pdfbox):
[image]

I found how to get transparency value from the resource, but I don't know how to match it with certain text.

```
double value = document.getFirstPage()
        .getResources()
        .getPdfObject()
        .getAsDictionary(PdfName.ExtGState)
        .getAsDictionary(new PdfName("GS1"))
        .getAsNumber(PdfName.ca)
        .getValue();
```

I also have a class which implement `IEventListener` and get many different information about text in PDF.

```
class TextRenderListener implements IEventListener {

 @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (type.equals(EventType.RENDER_TEXT)) {
            TextRenderInfo textRenderInfo = (TextRenderInfo) data;
            CanvasGraphicsState canvasGraphicsState = textRenderInfo.getGraphicsState();

    ...
   }
 ...
}
```

But fillAlpha and strokeAlpha always == 1.0 and I cannot find any reference to Resource ExtGstate

Parser:

```
new PdfDocumentContentParser(document).processContent(pageNumber, new TextRenderListener);
```

Pdf: https://filebin.net/34vm4sxl715oxy6z

Comment: Please share the PDF in question to reproduce your situation.

Comment: Here you are:
 https://filebin.net/34vm4sxl715oxy6z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that `fillAlpha` and `strokeAlpha` are always equal to `1` and that indeed was the case previously, but this was fixed recently and the fix is available in current `7.1.11-SNAPSHOT` version of iText. Here is the example code:

```
class TextRenderListener implements IEventListener {

    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (type.equals(EventType.RENDER_TEXT)) {
            TextRenderInfo textRenderInfo = (TextRenderInfo) data;
            float transparency = textRenderInfo.getGraphicsState().getFillOpacity();
            System.out.println(transparency);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        return new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(EventType.RENDER_TEXT));
    }
}
```

For your document it prints the following contents into the console (so the first piece of text is not transparent and the second one is transparent):

```
1.0
0.34902
```

To use the SNAPSHOT version you need to add the following Maven repository to your project:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>itext-snapshot</id>
    <name>iText Repository - snapshots</name>
    <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/snapshot</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: You made my day!
Thanks a lot!

p.s I spent 3 days trying to solve this...

Comment: is it possible to detect the existance of transparency in any object using iText 4 or iText 5 by looping over any of the page/content/resource object dictionary ?